# Create Next/Previous links Based Off Previous MySQL Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a membership database which can be searched and which returns a paginated list of results.

What I want to do/have, is that if someone clicks on a member profile from that list of search results, that profile can also use links to the next profile from the search results, or to the previous.

All this link needs to 'dynamically' include is the user id. Eg.

```
<p><a href = 'memberprofile.php?$userid'>Previous</a></p>
<p><a href = 'memberprofile.php?$userid'>Next</a></p>
```

The pseudo code for my results page is roughly:

```
Run query to find number of results which match search criteria
Calculate Number of pages of results and generate page number links
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //Pull out content from each matching row which match search criteria
}
```

So this gives me my search results. Great.

So in order to do what i want, I need to get the 'userid' of the row previous to AND next from the row the user actually clicks on.

Example if my results display user id's 3, 5, 12, 13, 22, 41 and the visitor clicks to view user 12 (a new page), how can I grab 5 & 13 to use as next/previous?

Additionally, assuming i can generate a next/previous link, and the visitor clicks it, how do i generate the previous/next buttons for that profile?

The way I'm thinking about it is its almost a secondary 'paging' script, but i can't get my head around it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (pseudo code too)

```
$prev_row= NULL;
$next_row=NULL;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  - this element is the $next_row for previous element, if it is not null, of course
  - the last element is the $prev_row for this element (or default NULL if this one is first)

  - Pull out content from each matching row which match search criteria

  - store this element so that you can use it in next element as the previous one
}
```